# Write to client in HttpApplication without HttpResponse object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Is there any way to write something back to the client without a `HttpResponse` object? I log unhandled exceptions in `Application_Error` of my `HttpApplication`, and I write a custom response back using `HttpApplication.Response.Write()`. However, if an error occurs during startup (i.e. before ASP.NET Web API has been properly set up), I get an exception if I try to access the `HttpApplication.Response` property. Is it possible to write a response using some other mechanism if the `Response` object isn't available?

Comment: Can you share with us the stacktrace?

Comment: Sure, if you'd like - redacted the namespaces/paths:

   at System.Web.HttpContext.get_Response()
   at ***.ErrorResponseHelper.WriteErrorResponse(HttpContext context, Exception exception) in C:\***\ErrorResponseHelper.cs:line 36
   at ***.Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\***\Global.asax.cs:line 39
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RaiseOnError()

Comment: @MartinWedvich Short answer: **No**. Not so short answer: The request is not available as yet during startup so there is no access.